# jquery double execution of single click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a jquery function that goes like this

```
$(".btn").click(function(e){
 alert("hello"); 
});
```

For some reason it gives two alerts. This stems from another script in a plugin I am using (found out as I turned the plugin off). In my script, I tried to unbind it, which gives me no fix. I have also used e.stopPropogation() which works, but then kills the plugin function. Is there a way to allow the plugin function to run its course, then for my function to perform once only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: You can do this by using a namespace to the click event of your plugin thereby triggering the click on the plugin's components over a different namespace and performing the click event mentioned above over a different namespace preventing any clashes.

Comment: Can you post more information such as your html code, the plugins you are using.

Comment: I have a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ArY5c/2/  with the plugin, when you click on a button the first time, it gives two alerts, then runs fine. At Rohan Reddy, I have been reading up on the namespace, not quite sure on how it works, could you point me in the right direction, pls

Comment: Have you tried event.stopImmediatePropagation()

Comment: I have tried that, unfortunately, it didn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your fiddle and i find this trouble was cause by the div with `data-uk-button-radio`, the `uikit.min.js` bind a click event on divs with `data-uk-button-radio` which will trigger all click event of div's children.

So using `event` to judge if this click action comes from mouse or script will solve this.

Like this:

```
(function(){
 $( ".uk-button" ).click(function( event ) {
 if(event.originalEvent)//only event from mouse has this property 
  alert("hello"); 
  // Do something
});
})(jQuery)
```

[**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ArY5c/4/).

Comment: Hi, thank you this seems to have solved the issue :), thank very much! Just another question regarding your answer. Would if(event.originalEvent) work for touches also, or would I need to add something like this if(event.orginalEvent && event.originalEvent.touches)

Comment: @Ant I don't know well about mobile jquery,but i think `if(event.originalEvent)` will work for touches also,if not,you can find a unique property of `event` in touches or script trigger by debug the two situations,there must have some properties can work.

Answer (score 0):

try this: based on your fiddle

```
$( ".uk-button" ).bind('click.uniqueEvent', function( event) {
    event.stopPropagation();


    alert("hello"); 
   // Do something
});
```

Then, when you want to unbind this particular event. you can just do:

```
unbind(".uniqueEvent")
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but it stops the plugin functions from working. Still trying to read up on namespace to see if there is something to fix it. Thanks for your suggestion.